# Select Element for dropdown list in robot automation

Tags: automation, robotframework

I'm newbie in Robot Framework and need your help with my problem. When I try to select an element from Dropdown list, the default class of this list is "select-dropdown" but when click it, the class will change to "select-dropdown active". So I cannot choose the right element even i used 
click element  xpath or css

So please help me with this case.

#### Default Class

[image: 1]

#### The Class change after clicking

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that this is not a class change, but a class addition. The original class name still applies. Using it depends on your personal preference but using xpath this could be crafted like:

```
//input[contains(@class, "select-dropdown")]
```

Comment: And for css locators it will be even easier — `input.select-dropdown` will match both elements, as space in `class` separates different classes

Answer (score 0):

My approach is just using the absolute xpath expression from root html to child node/element. I see your id is also dynamic and you should inform your web developer to make the static id for each element.

Solution using the absolute xpath expression.. So, you **must first get the absolute xpath** for both i) the element to click and ii) the select list. Install some xpath finding add-on/extension on your web browser to make it ease. Then you can do the following below.

```
# The xpath link used below is just an example only..

${xpath_click}=  Set Variable   /html[1]/body[1]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]
Wait Until Page Contains Element   xpath=${xpath_click}
Click Element   xpath=${xpath_click}
```

Then, we can use the `Select From List By Value` keyword to select from a drop-down list.

```
#The xpath link used below is just an example only..
${xpath_selectlist}=  Set Variable   //div[5]//div[2]//div[2]/select
Select From List by Value   xpath=${xpath_selectlist}  YOUR_SELECTION_VALUE
```